# Facebook Login tutorial code return "Sorry, something went wrong." when requesting permissions (scope)

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I copy / paste this code I found there : from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/

It works. But when I want to add a permission, ie : {scope: 'public_profile,email'} :

I got :

Sorry, something went wrong. We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can.

Here is the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head></head>
  <body>

    <h2>Add Facebook Login to your webpage</h2>

      <!-- Set the element id for the JSON response -->
    
      <p id="profile"></p>

      <script>
  
        <!-- Add the Facebook SDK for Javascript -->
  
        (function(d, s, id){
                              var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                              if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                              js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                              js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
                              fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')
        );


        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            <!-- Initialize the SDK with your app and the Graph API version for your app -->
            FB.init({
                      appId            : 'XXXX',
                      xfbml            : true,
                      version          : 'v18.0'
                    });
            <!-- If you are logged in, automatically get your name and email adress, your public profile information -->
            FB.login(function(response) {
                      if (response.authResponse) {
                           console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
                           FB.api('/me', {fields: 'name, email'}, function(response) {
                               document.getElementById("profile").innerHTML = "Good to see you, " + response.name + ". i see your email address is " + response.email
                           });
                      } else { 
                           <!-- If you are not logged in, the login dialog will open for you to login asking for permission to get your public profile and email -->
                           console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.'); }
            } , {scope: 'email'}); // I just only added ", {scope: 'email'})"
        };

      </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas? I have no errors in the Chrome console

Thanks